# Need advice on how to make an Angular app and Java as backend

Tags: java, angular, session, servlets

I'm a not a programmer but a programming enthusiast, I have learned java (specifically - basics, some of the advanced stuff, JDBC, collections, servlets, etc. I haven't learned any frameworks such as swing, spring, applets, etc. I have created a web app as my project after I learned java with servlets, HTML, CSS, jQuery. I used no frameworks of any sought. I started learning Angular 7 and I'm in the middle of it. I used servlets to manage my sessions for client-side and was very easy to talk to using post request using jquery and receive JSON obj in return, I used JSP to render the HTML code I wanted. So I could add a bit of code in every JSP page like so...:

```java
<%
String school=(String)session.getAttribute("school");  
if(school == "" || school == null){
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
%>
```

...and redirect the user if the session is null. I'm wondering what a similar solution would be in Angular since angular is independent of the server.

Comment: _Never_ invent security yourself, and _just don't_ invent a Web stack yourself. Use something like Spring Boot, which makes this sort of project extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage your sessions in a handful of ways. The go to way at writing this seems to be through the use of JWT (JSON Web Token). You could setup an API [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) in angular that handles this using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient). When it comes to redirecting there's a [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) class for that in Angular.

I understand this might be a bit overwelming, don't hesitate to ask if you need any more information. :)

Comment: I will look into this method, right now I'm just learning about directives and routing. Would you be able to guide me after I have completed my Angular course ? My objective is to convert the other web-app I've created into a complete Angular  front-end.